# Setting up Embedded Java DB System Directory?

Tags: java, netbeans

My application runs perfectly under Netbeans but when I build it and launch the jar file it comes up with Java Virtual Machine Launcher "A Java Exception has occured" pop-up.  I ran the java -myjar.jar and it just says a fatal error has occured.  I presume that it can't create my database at main and that's why it's coming up with this error.  I have implemented the Embedded Java DB system and and in order to set the database to be created, I have performed the following routine of code,

```
String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
String systemDir = userHomeDir + "\\LMB\\";

// Set the db system directory.
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:LMB; create=true;");
```

Do you think this is right or I'm missing something??!

I run the following in the command prompt,

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

And it only shows this error.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop>java -jar iDA.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/applicat
```

ion/SingleFrameApplication
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.application.SingleFram
eApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more

I'm sure there is main method in my application class.  I don't understand what this is supposed to mean!

Comment: Please post the full error message possibly including the stacktrace